# Update DeltaTable properties on S3

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I have a DeltaTable at aws S3 location `(s3://bucket/myDeltaTable)` which has a default table property `delta.logRetentionDuration set to 30 days`.

Is there a way I can set this property to `3 days` without deleting & recreating table?

I tried below command but it did not work:

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE delta.`s3://bucket/myDeltaTable` SET TBLPROPERTIES(delta.logRetentionDuration = \"2 days\")")
```

The error I got was:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: delta.s3://bucket/myDeltaTable
```

Does anyone have any idea on altering the metadata of existing delta table stored in s3?

Comment: are you using Databricks or something else?

Comment: Delta official docs says it’s limited to 7 days minimum. Question, does the log files being deleted to you after 30 days? Because for me it’s not.

Answer (score 0):

try to add those settings to your `SparkConf`:

"spark.sql.extensions" = "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension"

"spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog" = "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"